# Ratyrate stars not loading in production (heroku)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, raty

So ive got ratyrate working in development just fine by adding

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'ratyrate.js', "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
```

to the body of my view. Prior to this the stars would only load when the url was directly accessed or the page refreshed.

Now I am having the exact same issue (stars not loading when page is accessed through a link) when deploying my app on heroku!

I hope that this is enough info (happy to provide more) and that someone has faced this before/has any ideas! Thanks!

**solved - see answer**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was that I forgot to run `rake assets:precompile`. The solution for development mentioned in the question should work.

**SOLUTION**

Add `<%= javascript_include_tag 'ratyrate.js', "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>` to the head (seems to run faster) or body tag in your view.

Also add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ratyrate.js )`
 to **config/initializers/assets.rb**.

Then make sure you run `rake assets:precompile` to avoid looking as silly as me!

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

My way to fix it:

**jquery.raty.js**

rename `jquery.raty.js` to `jquery.raty.js.erb` and replace images options with asset_path, for example:

`cancelOff    : 'cancel-off.png'`

will become

```
cancelOff    : '<%= asset_path('cancel-off.png') %>'
```

---

**raty_helper.rb**

I have moved `rating_for` method from raty helper to one of my helpers files, I had to override some things anyway, like do not allow user to rate himself that didn't worked out of the box.

Changes I did in this file:

```
star_path    = options[:star_path]    || ''
star_on      = options[:star_on]      || image_path('star-on.png')
star_off     = options[:star_off]     || image_path('star-off.png')
star_half    = options[:star_half]    || image_path('star-half.png')
cancel_on    = options[:cancel_on]    || image_path('cancel-on.png')
cancel_off   = options[:cancel_off]   || image_path('cancel-off.png')
```

basically I removed the `/` before each image name, it was for example:

```
star_on      = options[:star_on]      || image_path('/star-on.png')
```

now I can push to heroku and it works as expected without having to run assets precompile on my local machine and push it all to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because image locations aren't referencing the asset pipeline. I had to create a new helper file to override the rating_for methods to pull in images from the asset pipeline.

1. Create a new helper file (**raty_helper.rb**) in **config/initializers**
2. Add "module RatyHelper" to as line 1 of new file
3. Copy line 2 through line 144  from https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate/blob/master/lib/ratyrate/helpers.rb into your new helper.