# Why is my raty stars not working/loading/appearing in Heroku although it works perfectly fine on development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raty

I tried all the solution I can found here like precompiling locally, changed jquery.raty.js to jquery.raty.js.erb and others but it doesn't worked for me.

I placed the star-half.png, star-off.png, and star-on.png in app/assets/images while the jquery.raty.js is in app/assets/javascripts

---

Solved:

Solution that worked for me thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku/18920064#18920064):

config/environments/production.rb

from:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ratyrate stars not loading in production (heroku)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291314/ratyrate-stars-not-loading-in-production-heroku)

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesn't fixed for me that's why I posted this same concern. Can you help me please?