# show action is not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

First time deploying on heroku and my app, which is working fine locally on heroku (logs) throws NoMethodError (undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass) for this line of code:

```
def show
  if @movie.reviews.blank?
    @average_review = 0
  else
    @average_review = @movie.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
  end
end
```

I checked the data with console and it has a movie, review and rating. I'd provide more code but I'm a beginner and have no idea where to check. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You can open  heroku console with `heroku run console` , you are getting this error because one of your @movie.reviews don't have rating value . so it is null. and round method not used with nil value

Comment: try to adding value in that review else handle that error.

Comment: @Vishal Yes, that was it thanks! I missed it because I did click on rating but I guess I have a problem with jquery.raty star rating. I thought it just doesn't show the stars but it's obviously not working at all.

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: @Vishal Yes, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168574/why-is-my-raty-stars-not-working-loading-appearing-in-heroku-although-it-works-p)'s the answer. Again, thanks for your help, it redirected me to where the problem really was.

Comment: yes, my pleasure.